# WireMock testcases always fail when calling an undefined

Tags: java, wiremock

I re-edit the question as it might be helpful for others.

I try to get used to testing clients against mocket http-endpoints using Wiremock.

The very easy test scenario includes

- a testcase that calls a stubbed endpoint (works well)
- a testcase that calls a non stubbed endpoint (fails)

The case with the non stubbed endpoint itself is successful but it seems that the used WireMockRule inspects the list of unmatched calls and throws an error when the list is not empty.

The test runs without error in earlier versions of Wiremock (1.43), actually I try it with version 2.21.

The test class looks like this:

```
public class HttpFetcherTest {

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(18089);

    @Before
    public void init() {
        // only one endpoint is mocked
        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/aBody.txt")).willReturn(
                aResponse().withStatus(200).withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain").withBody("aBody")));
    }

    /**
     * Test calls a defined endpoint. Runs smoothly.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void found() throws Exception {
        //call the mocked endpoint
        String result  = Request.Get("http://localhost:18089/aBody.txt").execute().returnContent().asString();
        // we expect the mocked return value from the stub
        assertTrue("aBody".equals(result));
    }


    /**
     * The test calls an endpoint that is undefined. Expected behaviour is: a HttpResponseException 
     * is thrown. This is successful but the test fails anyway as the list of unmatched matches in WireMockRule is inspected
     * and the unmatched call is found and interpreted as an error.
     * This means: test fails although it is successful.
     * 
     * This was not an issue in earlier versions of Wiremock - it runs perfectly in 1.43.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test(expected = HttpResponseException.class)
    public void notFound() throws Exception {
        // call an endpoint that is not mocked - we expect a HttpResponseException
        String result  = Request.Get("http://localhost:18089/NOT_FOUND").execute().returnContent().asString();
    }


}
```

I am puzzled....
Thanks , Ishiido

Comment: what exactly do you expect from calling an 'undefined endpoint'?

Comment: well: calling the undefined endpoint throws the exception wanted. Thats the test - could be useful for a lot of services whose behaviour in this case should be tested.  As I said: the test itself works perfectly, just the inspection of the list of unmatched calls makes problems...

Comment: As the question is currently written it is difficult to assess if and what is your problem. This requires going to external places and perform unknown actions. Please formulate your question and provide the observed and expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the WireMock sources I found the answer.

The inspection of the list of unmatched calls can be switched off by using a different constructor:

Replacing the line

```
@Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(18089);
```

by

```
@Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(options().port(18089), false);
```

solves the problem. 
Thanks!